# String replacement of `\` not giving what I expect. What gives?

Tags: c#, string

```
"Action was successful.\\nThank you.".Replace( @"\\", @"\");
```

yields

```
"Action was successful.\\nThank you."
```

What gives?

For the record, I want to store the values in the database with a \n, but at some point during getting read back it gets converted into this format. I'm not terribly concerned with stopping that behavior, I want the above listed problem fixed. This way I can gaurantee I'm not getting other garbage in the future.

Also, this doesn't work:

```
"Action was successful.\\nThank you.".Replace( @"\\n", @"\n" );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this string `"Action was successful.\\nThank you.".Replace( @"\\", @"\");`
you have a SINGLE backslash. The `\\n` is translated in a `\` and a `n` (a backslash + `n`), so the Replace doesn't replace anything (it's trying to replace TWO backslash with a single backslash.

In the debugger, if you want, you can watch a string in "text mode". If you go to the string value (where it's written what is contained in the string) there should be a down arrow. Click here and click on Text.